# Returning rows from database based on search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a product table with following schema:

`products (itemname VARCHAR(50), itemid INT(10));`

Sample records are shown below (`itemname`, `itemid`):

- **blackberry curve 3g (black), 1**
- **samsung ace, 3**
- **blackberry curve 3g (white), 2**
- **apple iphone 4 32gb (black), 4**

Now suppose user enters the query into the search box of the website and accordingly results are displayed. i.e. if user enters `blackberry` then Blackberry mobiles should be displayed

I am looking answers for the following questions:

1. How can search text be matched with the items? For example: user may
   enter `blackberry` in the search box then how it can be searched?
   Should I search for `blackberry` word as a sub-string of `itemname`
   column of the above table?
2. If the user enters two words like: `apple 32gb`. Now if I use the
   above mentioned method of sub-string then it wont work because there is no row in the table having `apple 32gb` as sub-string. How to search in this case?
3. If the user enters a very generic search text like: `mobiles`. In this case, all the mobile phones should be displayed. Matching the `itemname` as a sub-string will not work in this case also.
4. User may enter search text: `apple 32gb black color`. In this case, apple products of 32GB capacity and black color should be displayed.

I know that implementing the search 100% correct is not possible. I am just looking for hints/how to proceed. I am using PHP, MySQL, Apache.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of database is this, if MySQL you can enabled fulltext search on the field and then just a simple query will get you the results you expect.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for the answer. Will it help in searching for two-word-search-text like `samsung mobiles`? Also I don't think full text search will be able to generate results for generic queries like: `mobiles`, `black color mobiles` etc.

Comment: I added full text and searching to a site recently and it is searching article names and it has been returning great results in testing so far. There are lots of examples but check into this post for a good base, http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304.

Answer (score 1):

for many word searching I would do something like this:

```
$searchArray = explode(" ", $searchString);
foreach ($searchArray as $word)
{
    //add an OR clause to your sql query like the following
    $query .= "OR itemname like %".$word."%";
}
```

the other questions are far more complicated, but I hope this helps